# Установка python3.5 на Centos 6

Tags: python-3.5, pip, centos6

Приветствую. Собственно проблема даже не в самой установке python3.5, его удалось тривиально собрать из исходников, а в том что pip модуль отсутствует после установки, и через python3.5 get-pip.py не ставиться потом-что:

`zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available`

У меня вопрос - почему pip отсутствует и как его поставить. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При сборке Makefile решается так:

`./configure --with-ensurepip=install`

Answer (score 0):

```
# install pip
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Взято [отсюда](https://superuser.com/questions/292378/how-to-install-pip-and-easy-install-on-centos). Почему pip нет - не знаю. По хорошему python надо устанавливать через yum.

И установка через yum

```
rpm -iUvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
yum -y update
yum -y install python-pip
```